# Is my sample sufficient for PCA?

Tags: r, pca, sampling, sample-size

I’m working on a project for my stats class and I’m wondering if my sample size is sufficient for PCA; I keep seeing mixed recommendations so I figured I’d ask.

My sample size is 50 (unit of analysis is states). I have 7 variables after turning my one categorical variable into a binary one through one-hot encoding; prior to that I have 5.

I ran a correlation matrix and found that a sufficient amount were at or above 0.3; I also ran a Bartlett test and the p-value was less than .01. The only thing I’m stuck on is whether or not the sample size is causing this.

Comment: "Sufficient" for what purpose?  50 is certainly enough to calculate the PCA.  Sample size doesn't affect correlation and p-values are irrelevant for most PCA applications.